# How to navigate on click of button from storyboard that was reached from Swift UI framework?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, storyboard

I am new to Swift UI framework. I am stuck at a point. Out of multiple screens, I have two screens one built in Swift UI and another using storyboard. Now in the storyboard I have a button on click of which, I navigate to another screen.

Below is the code to navigate to next screen,

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: UIButton){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pdf")
//        UIApplication.topViewController().navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
//        return vc
//        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Could someone please guide on how to navigate to the next screen on click of button in the storyboard. I am getting issues in the lines that are commented above. Kindly help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to navigate to a `SwiftUI` screen on tap of button (that exist in storyboard)

```swift
import SwiftUI

@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: UIButton){
    let swiftUIView = SwiftUIView() // << Your view here.
    let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this info. I will try it now.

Comment: Suppose in the same Swift UI framework I have two storyboard screens where I wat to navigate from one storyboard screen to another? How would I do that? I have added the segue in the storyboard.. That works... But I want to perform some operation before navigating. How would I programmatically navigate between storyboard screens in a swift UI framework

Comment: You need to set identifiers for that screen & use `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier-here")`. Because SwiftUI does not know about segue

Answer (score 0):

**if you're using Storyboard**  You can have your main view (entry point) -> then add a second 'View Controller' on your Storyboard View. Then click the button on the project (so it's highlighted/defined). Then press control and drag the blue line across to the second View. You'll then be asked what you'd like to do. Either set it to 'Show as popup' (go above main entry point) or other options.
Hope this helps!